# How to total/calculate the row bottom based on column row in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

How to total/calculate the total rows based on rows in angular ag grid...

the total of january should be `5` and february `5`....

***list.component.ts***

```
 ngOnInit() {
        this.columnDefs.push(
      {
        'headerName': 'Style/Machine',
        'field': 'machineStyle',
      }
    );
    for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
      const record = {
        'headerName': this.monthNames[i].monthName,
        'children': [
          {
            'headerName': 'Total', 'columnGroupShow': 'closed', 'field': 'total',
            'valueGetter': function (params: any) {
              return params.data.assetCount;
            }
          }
        ]
      };

      this.rowData.forEach((key: any) => {
        if (this.monthNames[i].monthName === format(key.date, 'MMMM')) {
          record.children.push(
            {
              'headerName': 'PRN', 'columnGroupShow': 'open', 'field': 'assetCount',
              'valueGetter': null
            }
          );
        }
      });
      this.columnDefs.push(record);
    }
    console.log(this.rowData);
    this.pinnedBottomRowData = this.createData(1);
    // console.log(this.pinnedBottomRowData);

  }


      createData(count: number) {
        const result = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
          result.push(
            {
              machineStyle: 'Total Machine'
            },
            {
              machineStyle: 'Total',
            }
          );
        }
        return result;
      }
```

output
[image]

***also*** 
have a `columnpGroupShow` where it show the other `children` which is the ``` PRN``
if it show on the ```row bottom```

the output should be like this..
[image]

advance thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
let sum = [{x: 1}, {x: 2}, {x: 3}];
const total_sum = sum.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) {
        return accumulator + currentValue.x;
    },0);
console.log(total_sum);
```

`.reduce()` function is return the previous value means which value is returned at first time is stored in accumulater parameter of given code. And second value come on currentvalue parameter again return  a addition again store on accumulater parameter.it process working until array size. `.reduce()` is not working on blank array, so you need to check array is not empty. otherwise it throws the type error.

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom pipe

```
import { NgModule, Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({
  name: "sum"
})
export class SumPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any[], attr: string): any {
    return items.reduce((a, b) => a + b[attr], 0);
  }
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [SumPipe],
  exports: [SumPipe]
})
export class SumPipeModule {}
```

In your html use this way `<span>{{ studentArray | sum:'fees' }}</span>`
Here fees is the column you need to send

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sum-pipe-module)